# AWS Signature Error using Postman to access the AWS API Gateway when posting a binary

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway

Works fine when doing a GET request or even a POST request with raw JSON. But sending a file returns this error:

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. The Canonical String for this request should have been 'POST......."

Credentials are definitely correct.

Comment: You're following these directions and creating a new signature for each new request? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue posted on 3rd July: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3232

Will wait for the update